# TypeError: mysqli::real_connect(): Argument #3 ($password) must be of type ?string, bool given

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

So, I'm a begginer and I have just installed XAMPP on my windows machine, and it seemed to work fine. I made some changes to the config.inc.php as I wasn't able to drop the default databases, and since then I get this error when trying to access:

http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

I have uninstalled XAMPP using the uninstaller and then installed it again, but phpMyAdmin is still not working

Answer (score 0):

When I modified the config.inc.php I accidentally changed the value of 'extension' in this bit of code

```
/* Authentication type and info */    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

I changed it to this

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
```

And it worked like a charm